# Access camera in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, apache-flex, actionscript-3, mxmlc

In the following why is that the camera does not show up in the div.Is that am i doing anything wrong here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="test" style="display:block;"></div>
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('test').addBlock();">Call addBlock</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
  swfobject.embedSWF('test.swf', 'test', '300', '300', '9.0.124', 'expressInstall.swf');
</script>
```

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" width="300" height="300" creationComplete="init()">
 <mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.controls.Alert;
                    import flash.display.InteractiveObject;
        import flash.display.Sprite;
        import flash.media.*;
        import flash.net.*;

        public static var cam:Camera =  Camera.getCamera();
        public static var video:Video = new Video(10, 20);
        private function init():void
        {
            ExternalInterface.addCallback('addBlock', addBlock);
        }

        private function addBlock():void
        {
            //Alert.show("addBlock called");
            if(cam != null)
            {   
                cam.setMode(640, 480, 30);
                video.attachCamera(cam);
                addChild(video);

            }
            else
            {

                trace("No Camera Detected");
                Alert.show("No Camera Detected");
            }




        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>
  </mx:Application>
```

Comment: This can have a plentitude of reasons, starting with the possibility that your Javascript or SWF  file is not loading at all. This needs some debugging first to isolate the problem, e.g. using Firebug

Comment: No actually if i give a simple alert in the flex code it shows up..

Comment: Does "no camera detected" show up?

Comment: No..It asks for the camera access confirmation.And when i say allow.Nothing shows up..

Answer (score 1):

First what I would do is to make sure that the Flash is actually being embedded. If it is the case that the Javascript is working correctly then there are a few possible issues here. First I'm not positive but I would think that you wouldn't want to be attaching the camera to a video object, but instead to a video display:

```
<mx:VideoDisplay x="784" y="276" width="0" height="0" id="video"/>
```

And then do:

```
video.addChild(cam);
```

The second thing is that if you are using a Mac the standard getCamera() function doesn't work 100% of the time. What I would recommend you do is define your own get camera function which should look something like this:

```
private function getCamera():Camera{
    var camera:Camera;
    var index:int = 0;
    for (var i:int = 0; i < Camera.names.length; i++) {
        trace(Camera.names[i]);
        if (Camera.names[i] == "USB Video Class Video") { // for macs camera
                index = i;
        }
    }
    camera = Camera.getCamera(String(index));
    if (camera == null) {
        return null;
    }
    else {
        return camera;
    }
}
```

Basically some Macs have a default camera which is located in a weird place where the standard getCamera call doesn't work. This one should help. Good luck!

Comment: video.addChild(cam); has an error saying 
 Description Resource Path Location Type
1061: Call to a possibly undefined method addChild through a reference with static type flash.media:Video. test.mxml /test/src line 28 Flex Problem

Comment: Yes that seems like it's because your addChild method is being called on a video object instead of a videoDisplay. At least as far as I can tell...